# opengl or android 4.0 acceleration

Tags: android, opengl-es

I would like to build a Rummikub game.

If I will use andengine I must go with android > 4 
I heard that on Android 4.x  there is hardware acceleration. (how good is it ?)

Is it Android hardware acceleration as good as opengl  ?

Comment: I didn't got any answer, I will have to make a test and see. ...

Answer (score 0):

Just something to point out is that andengine is very old now and you may want to go with something else.  There is quite a few cross platform frameworks that may save you a lot of time

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/